# Prove that roots of cubic equation are real.

Tags: roots, real-numbers, cubics

The equation is $(x+4)(x+2)(x-3)+(x+3)(x+1)(x-5)=0$.

How do I prove that the all the roots are real and distinct?

Comment: Evaluate at $-5$, at $-5/2$, at zero, and at 6.

Comment: you can solve it easily by Cardano's method. https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiTtbTRurDVAhUIuI8KHYtwBJcQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ucdavis.edu%2F~kkreith%2Ftutorials%2Fsample.lesson%2Fcardano.html&usg=AFQjCNE9Uxbiga_ZynDYhuYd8jcnZgTbKQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=(x+4)(x+2)(x-3)+(x+3)(x+1)(x-5)$. Then

- since $-27=f(-4)<0<6=f(-3)$, there is a root in $(-4,-3)$;
- since $7=f(-2)>0>-12=f(-1)$, there is a root in $(-2,-1)$;
- since $-48=f(3)<0<13=f(4)$, there is a root in $(3,4)$.

Since it is a cubic equation, it can have no more roots. Therefore, all roots are real.